# How to specify numbered sections in Pandoc's PDF outline?

Tags: pdf, yaml, latex, markdown, pandoc

I managed to get numbered section and chapter with pandoc using markdown following sources :

```markdown
---
toc: true
numbersections: true
---

# Big title
## Section
# Another big title
## section
### subection
## pof
## pif
```

I used the following command to generate pdf document:

```bash
$ pandoc outlinetest.md -o outlinetest.pdf
```

Chapters and sections are numbered correctly :

[image]

But the numbers don't appear in outlines of evince pdf viewer.
Is it possible to display number in outlines with pandoc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `bookmarksnumbered` option of the hyperref package:

```
---
output: pdf_document
toc: true
numbersections: true
---
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}

# Big title
## Section
# Another big title
## section
### subection
## pof
## pif
```

[image]